# Tradingview pinescipt heiken ashi color change

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to write a code that sends alert when heiken ashi bars change colour but it keeps sending the alert every time the condition is true but I only want the alert to be triggered once the condition is met

```
    study("Heikin Ashi Candle Colour Change Alerts", overlay=true)

val = (open + high + low + close) / 4
up = val > val[1]
down = val <= val[1]

alertcondition(condition = up, title = 'Up Candle', message = ' - UP CANDLE')
alertcondition(condition = down, title = 'Down Candle', message = ' - DOWN CANDLE')

plotshape(up, title = 'Up Candle', style = shape.square, color = lime, location = location.bottom)
plotshape(down, title = 'Down Candle', style = shape.square, color = red, location = location.bottom)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple counter:

```
CountUP = 0
CountUP := nz(CountUP[1])
CountDOWN = 0
CountDOWN := nz(CountDOWN[1])

if up
    CountUP += 1
    CountDOWN := 0
    CountDOWN

if down
    CountUP := 0
    CountDOWN += 1
    CountUP
```